# Passing ForeginKey to CreateView from url

Tags: django, url, django-generic-views

I've been using examples from Django documentations, but so far it is not solving my problem: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user

So basicly I have this model:

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Trip, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

urls.py

```
path('trip/<int:pk>/discussion/', PostCreate.as_view(), name='trip-detail-discussion'),
```

views.py

```
# 1st attempt
class PostCreate(CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'tripplanner/postcreate.html'
    fields = ['title', 'content']
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['pk'] = self.kwargs['pk']
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.group = context.get('pk')
        # print(self.trip)
        print(form.instance.group)
        return super(PostCreate, self).form_valid(form)

# 2nd attempt
class PostCreate(CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'tripplanner/postcreate.html'
    fields = ['title', 'content']
    success_url = '/'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.trip = get_object_or_404(Trip, pk=kwargs['pk'])
        return super(PostCreate, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.group = self.trip.id
        print(form.instance.group)
        return super(PostCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Both attempts give me this error:

```
Cannot assign "1": "Post.group" must be a "Trip" instance.
```

Any ideas how to pass this to db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group should be `Type` instance not an integer.

```
 form.instance.group = self.trip
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was such a small error here. Thanks a lot